# Forwarding logs to splunk/graylog from syslog-ng

Tags: linux, syslog, splunk, syslog-ng, graylog2

I want to forward my apache and tomcat logs to my central log server.(splunk/graylog)

I have client systems with syslog-ng running.

How can I forward the logs?

Is it necessary to parse the logs? Can't I forward logs as they are?
do I have to edit the apache configuration also?

I was trying to get it done last one week. I had created an another question regarding this. But no hep found. 
[Forwarding log via syslog-ng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187893/forwarding-log-via-syslog-ng)
Anyone please look this.

update1:
This is my latest syslog-ng.conf

```
source s_all {
  internal();
  unix-stream("/dev/log");
  file("/proc/kmsg" program_override("kernel: "));
  file("/var/log/apache/access.log" follow_freq(1) flags(no-parse));
  file("/var/log/apache/error.log" follow_freq(1) flags(no-parse));
};
destination d_splunk {
  udp("ec2-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com" port(514));
};
log {
  source(s_all); destination(d_splunk);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Install an Universal Forwarder to your central log server (I'm assuming this is different box than your Splunk instance). Then monitor the path of your syslog. I don't know syslog-ng that well but the logs should be written so that it contains the hostname in the path somewhere like `/var/log/my_host_one/apache/access.log`. That way Splunk will use the correct hostname (see `host_segment` in [`inputs.conf`](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/admin/inputsconf)).

Also to test to make sure your UF is correctly connecting to your main Splunk instance (configured via [`outputs.conf`](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/admin/outputsconf)), try to search the UF's internal logs for `index=_internal host=your_uf_host`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I recommend you to check ansible ( https://docs.ansible.com/ ) . Instead of doing manually all the time.

```
    - name: Configure syslog forwarding
  copy:
    content: |
      *.* @localhost:514;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format
    dest: /etc/rsyslog.d/30-graylog.conf
    mode: 0644
    owner: root
    group: root
  notify:
    - restart collector
    - restart rsyslog
```

something like this will solve your problem.